# Android Multiwindow on Android 11 +

Tags: android, multi-window

I want to launch third-party apps on floating window I tried :

```
try {ActivityOptions mOptions = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
        Intent i = c.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT |
                          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                Class<?> cls = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityOptions");
                cls.getMethod("setLaunchWindowingMode", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE}).invoke(mOptions, new Object[]{new Integer(5)});
            Rect mBounds = new Rect(300, 0, 500, 650);
            mOptions = mOptions.setLaunchBounds(mBounds);
            c.startActivity(i, mOptions.toBundle());
        } catch (Exception e) {Toast.makeText(c, "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

This code works on on Android 10 and below but not on Android 11 and up what is wrong?

> I want to launch apps like this

[image: Multi window on Android pie]

Comment: more restriction from google -> W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ActivityOptions;->setLaunchWindowingMode(I)V (blocked,test-api, reflection, denied)